# Facebook Login Window hangs after logging in

Tags: facebook

When the user logs in successfully the window hangs up and it's title changes to: XD Proxy

There is a similar question that was supposedly solved but instead of posting the solution the user said: "I solved it. It was to do with my settings in Facebook's page." So I ended up knowing I have to change the settings page but no idea what.

My url in the settings page is: http://chusmix.com/ and my domain is chusmix.com. I'm currently trying the login button at http://www.chusmix.com/game

I don't need it to refresh since the login button refreshes to logged in by itself, I only need the window to close.

This is my code:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'146324722088262', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
  </script>
  <fb:login-button length="long" onlogin="signface_login();" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

Any info on how to fix this will be tremendously welcomed. I have been trying to fix it for the last 2 hours and I haven't been able to start anything else.

Thanks

Comment: can you please explain it little further ..for me that link is working fine.. do you want it to redirect you to any other page after login ??

Comment: Is it really working for you? I'm trying it here and the popup works perfectly but when you press Login the window doesn't close. I just want the popup to close and maybe the page to refresh.

Thanks

Comment: yeah i checked from different browser and its working in each...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I checked it in my other PC and it was working correctly too in all browsers. Don't know why it doesn't work in this one though. But that's alright for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw one of the solution i can think of is to set next url in fb login page to some page where you call window.close()
let me know if this is working fine....